# I tried to make BTC monitoring using python but it doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

I am new in python and when i run this code gives me this error pls help.   [Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bes6u.png)

```
    import requests
from datatime import datatime 

#https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD,JPY,EUR

URL = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym={}&tsyms={}"

def get_price(coin,currency):
    try:
        respone = requests.get(URL.format(coin, currency)).json()
        return respons
    except:
        return False

while True:
    date_time = datetime.now()
    date_time = data_time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    currentPrice = get_price(BTC,USD)
    if currentPrice:
        print(date_time, "BTC price: ", currentPrice, "$")
```

Comment: The error says *No module named 'requests'*. This is not a standard library module, so you have to install it into your environment. The magic word is `pip install requests` or on some Windows environment `py -m pip install requests`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed 'requests'?

Try this. 'pip install requests' on terminal